# How do I properly model message flow between entities in BPMN 2.0?

Tags: bpmn

Let's say that for this case I have the following implementations:

[image: Case 1]

[image: Case 2]

[image: Case 3]

Are any of these diagram correct according to the good practices of BPMN? Is there one that's "more correct" than another? I do think that the better and more clear implementation is the first one but I can't justify why the others could be possibly wrong.